# How can I get the value from custom radio button component in parent class

Tags: react-native

I have a custom radio button component. I am importing that to my parent form to create a dynamic fields of radio button from JSON file. I have multiple other views too. I am getting these views values and creating a JSON array in my parent form. I am stuck in how to get my custom radio buttons values and pass them to my method where i am creating JSON array of values.Here is my custom component radio button code

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

export default class RadioButton extends Component {
  state = {
    value: null,
  };

  render() {
    const { PROP } = this.props;
    const { value } = this.state;

    return (
      <View>
        {PROP.map((res) => {
          return (
            <View key={res.key} style={styles.container}>
              <Text style={styles.radioText}>{res.text}</Text>
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.radioCircle}
            
                onPress={() => {
                  this.setState({
                    value: res.text,
                  });
                }}
              >
                {value === res.text && <View style={styles.selectedRb} />}
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          );
        })}
        <Text> Selected: {this.state.value} </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginBottom: 15,
    alignItems: "center",
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
  },
  radioText: {
    marginRight: 35,
    color: "#000",
  },
  radioCircle: {
    height: 20,
    width: 20,
    marginRight: 10,
    borderRadius: 100,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: "#3740ff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  selectedRb: {
    width: 15,
    height: 15,
    borderRadius: 15,
    backgroundColor: "#3740ff",
  },
  result: {
    marginTop: 20,
    color: "white",
    fontWeight: "600",
    backgroundColor: "#F3FBFE",
  },
});
```

This is my main class.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import CheckBox from "@react-native-community/checkbox";
import { View, TextInput, Button, StyleSheet, Text } from "react-native";
const data = require("../json/registration.json");
import MyRadioButton from "../component/MyRadioButton";

class Registration extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      itemstorender: [],
      inputData: [],
      checked: "",
    };
  }
  addValues = (value, index) => {
    let dataArray = this.state.inputData;
    let checkBool = false;
    if (dataArray.length !== 0) {
      dataArray.forEach((element) => {
        if (element.index === index) {
          element.value = value;
          checkBool = true;
        }
      });
    }
    if (checkBool) {
      this.setState({
        inputData: dataArray,
      });
    } else {
      dataArray.push({ value: value, index: index });
      this.setState({
        inputData: dataArray,
      });
      // console.log('Data',dataArray);
    }
  };
  getValues = () => {
    console.log("Data", this.state.inputData);
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.renderData();
  }
  hideComponent(data) {
    // console.log("checkd",data)
    this.setState({
      checked: data,
    });

    console.log(this.state.checked);
  }

  renderData = () => {
    const result = data.info;

    var itemstorenderLocal = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      if (result[i].element == "TextInput") {
        let i_id = result[i].id;
        console.log("Ids : ", i_id);
        itemstorenderLocal.push(
          <TextInput
            key={result[i].id}
            placeholder={result[i].label}
            onChangeText={(value) => this.addValues(value, i_id)}
          />
        );
        this.setState({ itemstorenderLocal });
      }else if (result[i].element == "RadioButtons") {
        let i_id = result[i].id;
        // let options = console.log("Ids : ", i_id);
        itemstorenderLocal.push(
          <Text>{result[i].label}</Text>,

          <View style={styles.container}>
            <MyRadioButton
              PROP={result[i].options}
            />
          </View>
        );
     
        this.setState({ itemstorenderLocal });
      } else if (result[i].element == "button") {
        itemstorenderLocal.push(
          <Button
            key={result[i].id}
            title={result[i].label}
            onPress={() => this.getValues()}
          />
        );
      }
    }

    this.setState({
      itemstorender: itemstorenderLocal,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return <View>{this.state.itemstorender}</View>;
  }
}

export default Registration;
```

Comment: **Where** is your `let dataArray = this.state.inputData; [etc]` code located? Is it a hook? A reducer? Another component? "Parent class" is not accurate because the parent-class of `RadioButton` is `Component`, which is not your code.

Comment: Where are you using the RadioButton? the parent class code is not clear

Comment: @Dai  sorry for can't explaining properly. I edited my question please look into it again.

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan I edited my question please look into it again

Comment: Take a look at this article https://webomnizz.com/change-parent-component-state-from-child-using-hooks-in-react/ you just need to change it to class-based component